# How to add bar labels to a histogram on Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Using the Fifa 19 dataset, I'm trying to place the number of players within specific skill score intervals as labels on a histogram graph.

I'm reading the CSV file locally, although I put the URL link below to exemplify.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fifa_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KeithGalli/matplotlib_tutorial/master/fifa_data.csv')

bins = np.arange(40,101,10)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5), dpi=300)
bar_plot = plt.hist(fifa_df['Overall'], bins=bins)
plt.bar_label(bar_plot)
plt.xticks(bins)

plt.show()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'patches'

I need help with the error and also the logic of this function (I'm new to pyplot). I read answers to other questions and I don't quite seem to find the proper solution.

Comment: What line is the error occurring on? I also recommend you create a simplified dataset that reproduces this issue. I recommend taking a look at this SO post on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples.

Comment: just remove this line and it works: `plt.bar_label(bar_plot)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `bar_plot = plt.hist(fifa_df['Overall'], bins=bins)` to `count, n_bins, bar_plot = plt.hist(fifa_df['Overall'], bins=bins)`

The [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) returns a tuple of things, instead of the container you need for `bar_label`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [plt.hist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) returns a tuple containing the values of the histogram, bin edges, and the patches (bar containers).

`plt.bar_label()` on the other hand takes the container as an Argument (check [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)).

Which means you can change your code like this:

```
plt.bar_label(bar_plot[2])
```

I then got this output:
[image: histogram with bar labels]

Comment: The code would be far easier to understand (and to maintain) if you'd replace `bar_plot = plt.hist(...)` by something like `values, edges, patches = plt.hist(....)` and then use `patches` instead of the cryptic `bar_plot[2]`.

Comment: True... but its an easier and faster solution. But of course you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I am a relatively new python coder so I do apologize if this may not be of much help. But pyplot is pretty much an API for Pythons matplotlib, an alterative to using MATLAB, and creating visuals using Python. But I noticed you used plt.bar_label which could be why you're receiving that error. I've used plt.hist before when trying to create charts in python so that could possibly help, assuming the error in your code is due to the plt.bar_label. I hoped I could give some help.